# Angular ng-model not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to bind Json data into ng-model inside ng-repeat it gives error.

**html :**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
        <table>
            <th>
                <td>add</td>
                <td>edit</td>
                <td>delete</td>
            </th>
            <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                <td>
                    <input id="add{{category.id}}" ng-model="add{{category.id}}" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="edit{{category.id}}" ng-model="edit{{category.id}}" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="del{{category.id}}" ng-model="del{{category.id}}" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Js :**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {   
    $scope.selection = {
        ids: {"50d5ad": true}
    };
    $scope.categories = [ 
        {"name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , 
        {"name": "General", "id": "687ffr" },
        {"name": "Activities", "id": "678ffb" },
        {"name": "Regards", "id": "678fff" },
        {"name": "Thanks", "id": "678fer" },
        {"name": "Goes", "id": "678fgf" },
        {"name": "Oppertnities", "id": "674ffr" },
        {"name": "Convince", "id": "654ffr" },
        {"name": "Mopols", "id": "623ffr" } 
    ];    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wg4un1x/)

Comment: use ng-model="add[category.id]". '{{}}' is only used to fill up angularjs scope variables with normal html code. using 'ng-' for example in ng-model, or ng-repeat etc, you're can access the angular scope variables directly because you have already stated that you're talking to Angular

Comment: tried your fiddle and got "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wg4un1x/

Comment: look this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hKWRMj704uFinS3eP3pw?p=preview, the edit,add or delete data are storage in the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Shay` already mentioned you cannot use `{{}}` within ng-model this way. Here you have an example how you could implement it:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {  
    $scope.selection_add = {};
    $scope.selection_edit = {};
    $scope.selection_delete ={};
    $scope.categories = [ 
        {"name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , 
        {"name": "General", "id": "687ffr" },
        {"name": "Activities", "id": "678ffb" },
        {"name": "Regards", "id": "678fff" },
        {"name": "Thanks", "id": "678fer" },
        {"name": "Goes", "id": "678fgf" },
        {"name": "Oppertnities", "id": "674ffr" },
        {"name": "Convince", "id": "654ffr" },
        {"name": "Mopols", "id": "623ffr" } 
    ];    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>add</th>
                  <th>edit</th>
                  <th>delete</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_add'}}" ng-model="selection_add[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_edit'}}" ng-model="selection_edit[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_delete'}}" ng-model="selection_delete[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        <h1>Add</h1>
        {{selection_add}}
        <h1>Edit</h1>
        {{selection_edit}}
        <h1>Delete</h1>
        {{selection_delete}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to store the information inside the original array you could implement it this way:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [ 
        {"name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , 
        {"name": "General", "id": "687ffr" },
        {"name": "Activities", "id": "678ffb" },
        {"name": "Regards", "id": "678fff" },
        {"name": "Thanks", "id": "678fer" },
        {"name": "Goes", "id": "678fgf" },
        {"name": "Oppertnities", "id": "674ffr" },
        {"name": "Convince", "id": "654ffr" },
        {"name": "Mopols", "id": "623ffr" } 
    ];    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>add</th>
                  <th>edit</th>
                  <th>delete</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_add'}}" ng-model="category.add" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_edit'}}" ng-model="category.edit" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_delete'}}" ng-model="category.delete" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>

        {{categories}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm planning to load categories from database, and post the selection to server for user privilege setting.

Comment: You can use the snippet above, because you could just upload the 3 objects. On the server you iterate over all keys in the lists which are the IDs of the selected categories

Comment: I have included `$scope.appdata.selection_add = {}; $scope.appdata.selection_edit = {}; $scope.appdata.selection_delete ={};` and i'am able to access post data as `selection_delete,selection_edit,selection_add..` Thanks @boindiil

Answer (score 5):

You cannot write `{{}}` within ng-model like `ng-model="del{{category.id}}"`. Use an array/object hash instead. 
For example: `ng-model="del[category.id]"`

Comment: @AvinVarghese it is working you just need to create new object on scope otherwise you will get undefined error. 
$scope.add = {};
$scope.edit= {};
$scope.del= {};

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `add{{category.id}}` use `add[category.id]` and so on, define `add`, `edit` and `del` as scope variables in controller.

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <td><input id="add[category.id]" ng-model="add[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
    <td><input id="edit[category.id]" ng-model="edit[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
    <td><input id="del[category.id]" ng-model="del[category.id]" type="checkbox">{{category.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```